# Pivot some row values to a columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2012

I am trying to pivot some row values to a column, below is what I am trying to achieve.

**My Current Schema:**

```
+------+----------+
|  ID  |   name   |
+------+----------+
|   01 |  Vsp lan |
| 0121 |  abn     |
| 0122 |  abb     |
| 0123 |  vsp     |
|   02 |  Apn lan |
| 0211 |  add     |
| 0221 |  acd     |
+------+----------+
```

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**

```
+-----+--------+-------+---------+
| kod |   ID   | name  |   lan   |
+-----+--------+-------+---------+
|  01 |   0121 |   abn | vsp lan |
|  01 |   0122 |   abb | vsp lan |
|  01 |   0123 |   vsp | vsp lan |
|  02 |   0211 |   add | Apn lan |
|  02 |   0221 |   acd | Apn lan |
+-----+--------+-------+---------+
```

but it skips rows when name and lan have similar values, in this case it skips the row with the name value vsp.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID VARCHAR(5),[name] VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
 ('01','Vsp Ian')
,('0121','abn')
,('0122','abb')
,('0123','vsp')

,('02','Apn Ian')
,('0211','add')
,('0221','acd')
;

SELECT a.id as kod, b.id as ID, B.name as name, a.name as lan
FROM @table a
inner join @table b on CHARINDEX(a.id,b.id) = 1 and CHARINDEX(b.name,a.name) = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this fixes my problem.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID VARCHAR(5),[name] VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
 ('01','Vsp Ian')
,('0121','abn')
,('0122','abb')
,('0123','vsp')
,('02','Apn Ian')
,('0211','add')
,('0221','acd')
,('03','Ubb Ian')
,('0301','afg')
,('0302','ampx');


SELECT
 kod = ct.id
,ot.ID
,ot.[name]
,Ian = ct.[name]
FROM @table ot
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ID,[name] FROM @table WHERE [name] LIKE '%[lan]%') ct
WHERE len(ot.ID) > 2 
AND LEFT(ot.id,2) = ct.id;
```

Comment: Very nicely done, the little, subtle things, sometimes make all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I assume that you want to map the Van_ian with other names, if the van_ian `kod` is start of the id of names. E.g, 01 is start of 0121, 0122.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(id CHAR(10), name varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @table
values
('01','vsp ian'),
('0121','abn'),
('0122','abb'),
('02','vsp ian'),
('0211','add'),
('0221','acd');

SELECT ct.id as kod,ot.id, ot.name,ct.name as ian FROM @table as ot
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT distinct id, name from @table WHERE name like 'vsp%'
) as ct(id,name)
WHERE ot.name not like 'vsp%'
and LEFT(ot.id,2) = ct.id
```

```
+-----+--------+-------+---------+
| kod |   id   | name  |   ian   |
+-----+--------+-------+---------+
|  01 |   0121 |   abn | vsp ian |
|  01 |   0122 |   abb | vsp ian |
|  02 |   0211 |   add | vsp ian |
|  02 |   0221 |   acd | vsp ian |
+-----+--------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward approach I can think of is a self join, where one id starts with the other

```
SELECT a.id as kod, b.id as ID, B.name as name, a.name as laen
FROM table_name a
inner join table_name b on CHARINDEX(a.name,b.name) = 1 and CHARINDEX(b.name,a.name) = 0
```

This should work for your example, but if the are also longer ids, the result may be strange

Answer (score 0):

I am observing a pattern in the values of `ID`. For example, IDs `0121, 0122` can be categorised to ID `01`. Similarly, IDs `0211, 0221` can be categorised to ID `02`. 
Based on this assumption, this query should do :

```
select 
    tb1.ID as kod, 
    tb2.ID as ID, 
    tb2.name as name, 
    tb1.name as laen 
from tableName tb1 join tableName tb2 
on tb1.ID != tb2.ID and LOCATE(tb1.ID,tb2.ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Venkataraman R your answer was very close, I tweaked it a bit to match his output.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID VARCHAR(5),[name] VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
 ('01','Vsp_Ian')
,('0121','abn')
,('0122','abb')
,('02','Apn_Ian')
,('0211','add')
,('0221','acd')
,('03','Ubb_Ian')
,('0301','afg')
,('0302','ampx');

SELECT
 kod = ct.id
,ot.ID
,ot.[name]
,Ian = ct.[name]
FROM @table ot
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ID,[name] FROM @table WHERE [name] LIKE '%[_]%') ct
WHERE ot.[name] NOT LIKE '%[_]%'
AND LEFT(ot.id,2) = ct.id;
```

Comment: I only changed the last code to     WHERE [name] LIKE '%[lan]%') ct
WHERE len(ot.ID) > 2